# Linker error (2028) when migrating project from VS 2005 (XP) to VS 2008 (Windows 7)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, windows-7, managed, linker-errors

I am migrating a solution from Visual Studio 2005 (Windows XP) to Visual Studio 2008 (Windows 7). The solution contains several class libraries (dlls). These libraries are written in C#. One library (named "SDEWriter"), however, is written in C++. This library is a CLR project and links to external libraries written in native C. I don't have access to the C code.

Compiling and linking the project in VS 2005 went fine. But in VS 2008, I get the following linker error:

***error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000E) "extern "C" long __stdcall SE_error_get_string(long,char *)" (?SE_error_get_string@@$$J18YGJJPAD@Z) referenced in function "public: static bool __clrcall SDEWriter::SDEfuncs::Error(long,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)"***

What is interesting: when I make "SDEWriter" a static library (lib) instead of a dll, everything works fine!!!

Some additional information about the "SDEWriter" project properties:

- Common Language Runtime Support: Old Syntax (/clr:oldSyntax)
- Additional Include Directories: path to the include folder of the external C header files
- Additional Libary Directories: path to the external libs
- Additional Dependencies: all required external libs

I have searched this site and the web, but I haven't found a solution. I would be very glad if anyone could help! Thanks a lot in advance.

Barbara

Answer (score 0):

this would have been impossible for you to solve. It was an ESRI problem. See: [ArcGIS forum thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/28031-Problems-migrating-ArcSDE-C-SDK-project-to-Visual-Studio-2008-%28Windows-7%29?p=94355#post94355)